# Tkinter bitmap not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to receive information from an API. My problem is that i keep getting an error like this :
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "weather_icons/04n.png" not defined

A part of the code is here .... would appreciate if somebody can enlighten me because i tryed to move the pictures from the "weather_icons" folder into the main folder , doesn't work, i tryed to use .gif instead of .png, doesn't work....

```
    if weather:
        location_lbl["text"] = "{}, {}".format(weather[0], weather[1])
        image["bitmap"] = "weather_icons/{}.png".format(weather[4])
        temp_lbl["text"] = "{:.2f}°C, {:.2f}°F".format(weather[2], weather[3])
        weather_lbl["text"] = weather[5]
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Can't find city {}".format(city))
```

Line 3 gives me that error.

Comment: We need minimal reproducible code, not just mere part of code as we don't know what those names are.

Comment: The `bitmap` option only deals with a few built-in B&W icons, or B&W files in .xbm format - a .png file is never going to work with it.  You want the `image` option - but that doesn't take a filename, it needs an actual image object (that was perhaps loaded from a file) - either Tkinter's own `PhotoImage` (may only support .gif, depending on Tkinter version) or the `ImageTk` class from the PIL/Pillow module.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are (at least) *two* potential problems here.

The first (and the most likely) is the location of your graphic (`png`) file. If your working directory is not the one containing the `weather_icons` directory, it won't find it. You can check this by doing something like:

```
import os
os.system("pwd")
os.system("ls -al")
os.system("ls -al weather_icons/{}.png".format(weather[4]))
```

and seeing if you're in the correct directory and the file exists.

To fix that, you'll either have to make sure your working directory is as expected, or find a way to generate an absolute path to the graphic file.

Secondly, it may be the file format is not supported by the `image` type (less likely, but since you haven't shown the creation of that variable, it's unclear at the moment what it is - that's something you may want to add to the question), or that the graphic file itself is corrupted.

You have rightly stated that you've also tried it with a `gif` file, and I assume that was a *real* `gif`, not just renaming the `png` file. In any case, you may want to try a very simple set of other image files to confirm.